# Updating Mysql text column with a single quote mark in it.

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-apps-script

I realize this might not be the correct way, and this isn't going into a production environment but I'm trying to update a table with a text column and the text I am trying to update has single quotes in it. I'm writing a javascript script through a google spreadsheet to update with and the text I'm updating has single quotes in it so when I do a query like

`SQLstatement.executeUpdate("UPDATE Products SET Desc_Short = '" + description + "' WHERE ProductID = '" + productID + "'");`

it will escape on single quotes. Is there a function in mysql or in apps script to update this?

Comment: Why the [tag:google-apps-script] tag?

Answer (score 1):

You should parameterize your query.  It will solve your problem and prevent sql injection.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html